# how to center model content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal dialog who's html is below. The picture that is shown should be centered but i cant seem to center it.

Anybody have a solution?

```
       <!-- modal popup dialog-->
       <div class="modal fade centered" id="image-gallery" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog centered">
                <div class="modal-content siteImageButton">
                    <div class="modal-body text-center">
                        <img id="image-gallery-image" class="img-responsive" src="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Clarification: I want the img to be centered in the modal div. I have no text in modal div.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `img-responsive` applies some width styles which could be affecting alignment...

Comment: Any you care to suggest?

Comment: OK will add an answer for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.img-responsive has the following styles applied:

```
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

`display:block` means `text-align:centre` which is inherited from `text-center` will have no effect.

If you remove the `.img-responsive` class, your image will be centred.

```
<div class="modal fade centered" id="image-gallery" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog centered">
        <div class="modal-content siteImageButton">
            <div class="modal-body text-center">
                <img id="image-gallery-image" src="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <!-- modal popup dialog-->
   <div style="text-align: center;" class="modal fade centered" id="image-gallery" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog centered">
            <div class="modal-content siteImageButton">
                <div class="modal-body text-center">
                    <img id="image-gallery-image" class="img-responsive" src="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Edit:**

```
<body class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-offset-6 centered">
          <img id="image-gallery-image" class="img-responsive" src="" />
    </div>
</body>
```

**Edit2:**
"Bootstrap's spans are floated to the left. All it takes to center them is override this behavior."

like so:

```
.center {
     float: none;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
}
```

and than:

```
<div class="span7 center"> box </div>
```

Comment: Thx, do you know a way to do using existing bootstrap css?

Comment: this does not work btw - img still on left. See my clarification in question. thx

Comment: It does work, I just tested it in jsfiddle.  Yes see my edit for bootstrap css way

Comment: Not in mine, i copied yours verbatum and tested in chrome, img is flush to left of modal

Answer (score 0):

```
.text-center{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: try adding an important flag to the both above and see what happens, if they work its due to styling already applied.